# Is Centos compatible with Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, centos

If it isn't does anyone know of a connector that is worthy of a high volume production environment?  I am looking to create a php app that connects to MSSQL Server 2012
TIA